# Kernel Panic while Installing Ubuntu 12.10 from USB Drive

Tags: kernel

Good evening,

I recently looked into installing Ubuntu alongside my Windows. I was able to mount the iso on a USB drive using Universal USB Installer. I verified it with the MD5sum utility and the hash is correct. When installing, I can get to the screen where I choose the boot order, select the USB drive, and then I get to a screen where Ubuntu seems to be 'loading' (purple background with Ubuntu logo and name in the middle). Then, all of a sudden, I get a "Kernel Panic - Not syncing: fatal exception in interrupt" error message. My specs :

Intel Core 2 Duo CPU T5850 @ 2.16 GHz / 4 GB of ram / Packard Bell computer from 2007. / Windows 7 Ultimate x64 installed. What should I do now ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be an hardware failure using Ubuntu software architecture... That fault is hard to discover, my guess is CPU overload or some bridge overload due to high speed disk communication... I have a similar situation when I boot from USB3 port, but, if I boot in the USB2 port everything works, which proves that software and configuration is OK, the solution is just to make things work slower!